If $(a_{n_1}-a_n)/(b_{n+1}-b_n) \to A$, then $a_n/b_n \to A$.
Suppose $\{ a_n \}$, $\{ b_n \}$ are monotone, strictly decreasing sequences of positive real numbers converging to $0$. Prove that if there exists a limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}=A$$
then, $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n/b_n=A$.
Notably, we can see
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n} \right|=\left|\frac{a_n}{b_n} \right|\cdot \left| \frac{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1}{\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}-1} \right|$$
Assuming the truth of the problem statement, it seems like the way to go is to prove that the right-most sequence converges to one so that $|a_n/b_n|$ converges to A, assuming that $A \ne 0$. If $A=0$, then the limit on the right-hand side need not converge at all. I've found this quite challenging to prove, however. In fact, I can't really make any progress at all.
It's worth noting that since $a_{n+1}/a_n<1$, and so $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le 1$, and the same goes for $b_{n+1}/b_n$. I don't think this is actually helpful, however, as they can still easily converge to something less than one, but still be different. However, if we could prove somehow that they necessarily had the same limit, the problem would be solved.
An alternative method is to show
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}-\frac{a_n}{b_n} \right)=0$$
however, this process becomes quite convoluted quite quickly, as combining the terms makes the arithmetic quite messy.
I'm sure this comes down to a simple arithmetic trick, combining terms in the right way, but as of yet, I've been unable to see it.

Is this the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem? If so, you can find many proofs on math.se and elsewhere on the web. Do a google search.

Stolz-Cèsaro theorem does not require that $a_n$ is monotone. Perhaps there is a simpler proof for this case.

@ajotatxe: It seems that this (monotonicity)  is already assumed in the OP.
